# How to conditionally include script element in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to conditionally include a chat on my page:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <!-- some code -->

  <script type="text/javascript" ng-if="expression">
    window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
    d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
    _.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");
    $.src="//v2.zopim.com/?my-zopim-id";z.t=+new Date;$.
    type="text/javascript";e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,"script");
  </script>
</body>
```

but it seems that the chat script gets executed before `ng-if` directive.

How can I make my Angular app to check the condition first and then execute the script from `<script>` tag?

Comment: You can't do it with ng-if you will have to put an if statement in the actual javascript.

Comment: @BobBrinks You can.

Comment: @estus Ah yes i see. You probably shouldn't.

Comment: @BobBrinks That's true!

Comment: How about a very simple ```<div ng-if="condition" ng-include="file/with/javascript/code.html"></div>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline Javascript will always have priority over Angular (parsed first by the browser). The best way is to inject/execute the javascript inside your controller with a condition or creating a directive.

Comment: could you explain the solution in more detail?

Answer (score 4):

It can be achieved with a trick:

```
  <script ng-if="..." type="{{ 'text/javascript' }}">
    ...
  </script>
```

The binding will prevent the script from being executed in normal way.

Notice that the above will work only when jQuery was loaded (prior to Angular), due to the way how Angular's jqLite implementation treats `<script>` elements.

The cleaner way would be a directive that does the same as `<script>` above but has safeguards that would prevent it from multiple executions (notice that putting `<script>` into directive's template has the same requirements on jQuery as the solution above).

Comment: interesting way

Answer (score 0):

A native and light weight approach, i.e. no jQuery, no-Angular directives, would be to use something like https://github.com/anywhichway/scriptswitch.